# count students from table where join mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the databaase in icon below. I want

1. to count all students from Subject with name Psychology and class with name Class5.

2. the percentage of students with status "Something" from subject  with name Psychology and class with name Class5.
3. All students and the class name from Class "Class6" that are male.

I've tried for example

(in english:)

```
SELECT COUNT(student_name) AS NumberOfStudents FROM student_srms JOIN class_srms JOIN subject_srms WHERE class_srms.class_name='Class5' AND subject_srms.subject_name='Psychology'
```

But returns NumberOfStudents = 20, but 20 are all student entries.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue likely stems from your `FROM` clause. It's not enough to just say `JOIN`. You need to specify the relationship of the columns between the two tables being joined with an `ON` clause:

```
FROM student_srms 
    JOIN class_srms 
        ON student_srms.student_id = class_srms.student_id
    JOIN subject_srms
        ON class_srms.subject_id = subject_srms.subject_id
```

I believe in `MySQL` there is a `NATURAL JOIN` which will tell `mysql` without an `ON` clause to just join on column names that are similar between the two tables, but that feels dirty to me and could cause failures later on in an applications lifecycle if new columns are introduced to tables that share names, but not relationships, so I would just steer clear of that.

I have a suspicion that your diagram showing tables/columns is incorrect based on the error you are reporting in the comments. Instead, try (and I'm totally guessing blind here at this point):

```
FROM student_srms
    JOIN student_class
        On student_srms.student_id = student_class.class_id
    JOIN class_srms 
        ON student_class.class_id = class_srms.student_id
    JOIN subject_srms
        ON class_srms.subject_id = subject_srms.subject_id
```

That adds in that `student_class` relationship table so you can make the jump from student to class tables. Fingers crossed.

Comment: student table doesn't have subject_id. Subject_id and Class_id that refers on Student_id are in Student_class table.

Comment: What I wrote doesn't refer to a `subject_id` in the `student_srms` table, so that shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: Reurns: Unknown column 'class_srms.student_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Interesting. Your diagram of your table schema shows that table `class_srms` has a column `student_id`. Does it not, in reality/your database, have that column? I'm guessing your diagram is incorrect.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggested change. I'm making some assumptions 1) Your diagram is incorrect 2) That the only way to get from `student_srms` to `class_srms` is thorugh the `student_class` table.